# Chapter name on the left and section name on the right in the header

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I am trying to add a header on the top of each page of my document. I want to have each chapter's name on the left and section name on the right (flushrigt).

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[R]{\itshape \nouppercase \rightmark}
\fancyhead[L]{\itshape \nouppercase Chapter \arabic{chapter}}

\setlength{\headheight}{14.5pt}

\begin{document}
\chapter{This is a chapter}
\section{This is a section}
\eject
ABC
\eject
def
\eject
ghi
\end{document}
```

Also, I want to have the header starting from the first chapter (no header on the list of figures and similar pages), and no chapter name (but a header with 'bibliography') on bibliography pages.

Thank you.

Comment: As for your second thing you wrote, I am quite sure that list of figures pages use the `plain` page style. So you would need to alter that page style by means of `\fancypagestyle{plain}{...}`.

Comment: I think that it is more appropriate to ask about it in a different question. I think that you would need to define a new page style, as explained in §12 of the `fancyhdr` manual, by something like `\fancypagestyle{biblio}{\fancyhead[R]{Bibliography}}`. Then, before the `\printbibliography` command, put `\pagestyle{biblio}`. But I just tried it and apparently it doesn't make any effect, probably because that the first page of the cited works has page style `plain`, which we never made any change to. So I can't help you more than that.

Comment: Thank you very much. The answer below gives me the major part of my question. I avoid adding a header on the bibliography page. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to redefine `\chaptermark` and `\sectionmark` to use only the chapter/section name.

Also for the second part of the question, start with `\pagestyle{plain}`, and after the TOC,LOF,LOT use `\pagestyle{fancy}` (after a `\newpage`).

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[R]{\bfseries \rightmark}
\fancyhead[L]{\bfseries \leftmark}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}}

\setlength{\headheight}{14.5pt}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{plain}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\newpage
\pagestyle{fancy}
\chapter{This is a chapter}
\section{This is a section}
\newpage
ABC
\newpage
def
\newpage
ghi
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! That's what I indeed needed! How can I make the font bold and not italic?

Comment: Use `bfseries` instead of `\itshape`.

Comment: Answer adapted, also added answer to second part of question.

Comment: On the bibliography page, I see the text "bibliography" on both sides, that is, in the chapter name and section number. I need just one. The others work perfectly.

Comment: Just before the bibliography, use `\newpage\fancyhead[R]{}`. I think this will solve that.